# Python convert part of object to json

Tags: python, json

I have a Python object that looks like:

```
import json

class ExampleObject():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tag = ''
        self.path = ''
        self.host = ''
        self.access = ''
        #self.uuid = ''
        self.attribute = ''

    def dump_to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

By using dump_to_json, I can convert the whole object to JSON, but I want to convert only some of these properties, for example, `tag`, `path`, `host`, to JSON, and ignore the rest..  Is there a simple way to pick and choose what object variables we can send to JSON?

Example code:

```
x = ExampleObject()
x.tag = '/tag/exampletagName'
x.path = '/prj/its/a/path/tag/exampletagName.fil'
x.host = 'server-host-name'
x.access = 'private'
jsonText = x.dump_to_json()
```

puts:

```
{"tag":"/tag/exampletagName", "path":"/prj/its/a/path/tag/exampletagName.fil", "host":"server-host-name","access":"private"}
```

and I want

```
{"tag":"/tag/exampletagName", "path":"/prj/its/a/path/tag/exampletagName.fil", "host":"server-host-name"}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, is there a specific reason you're setting attributes after creating the class object? I was thinking it might be easier to just pass the params into the `__init__` method.

Comment: @rv.kvetch, I did it here for simplicity, but in my need, the object is filled from several different sources, and each source is guaranteed to be incomplete.  There's about 4000 lines of other code that is missing, and the decision was just made yesterday to move away from Excel, Notepad, et al, and into JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just add those fields to the dump which are needed.

```
def dump_to_json(self):
    return json.dumps({'tag': self.tag, 'path': self.path, 'host': self.host})
```

Comment: Yep, this works.

Comment: If you have this issue, and you are getting a '(' has no closing brace error, please check the parens '{' and '}' are correctly placed.